# Input type datetime-local won't save to database having field type datetime in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a form which has an input type of datetime-local. However, Im unable to process it in my views for saving to the database. Im not using Django forms. How can I do it please?

Please help me :((

Error message: "DateTimeField %s received a naive datetime (%s
)"

Here is my code snippet:
html file

```
<label>Scheduled Date and Time<label>                        
<input type="datetime-local" 
id="test_datetime" name="test_datetime" id="test_datetime">
```

views.py

```
def add_test(request, pid):

    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        messages.warning(request, "Please login first")
        return redirect('login')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        test_datetime = 
        datetime.strptime(request.POST['test_datetime'],'%Y-%m- 
        %dT%H:%M')

    and it continues....
```

Answer (score 0):

A `datetime` can either be timezone aware or timezone naive.

A naive `datetime` object contains no timezone information, however Django requires that all `datetime` objects saved in the database are timezone aware. You can determine if a `datetime` object is naive by checking the `tzinfo` property: `datetime.datetime.now().tzinfo == None`.

Your error is a result of `datetime.strptime` creating a naive timezone.

For more information on timezone's in Django, and how it recommends storing them in your database using forms, take a look at the [timezone documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zones).

Comment: how do I fix this code provided that I want the exact date and time that has been selected by  the user in the form?